# Discord Py, Sending messages in any channel via ID

Tags: python, discord.py

I got the following command:

```
@client.command()
async def send(ctx, channel, *, content):
    channel = client.get_channel(id)
    await channel.send(content)
```

Setting the `channel=None` doesn't change anything and the error:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
```

`async def send(ctx, channel=None, *, content):` (doesn't change anything - error remains the same)

Example: I want to send a message to a channel I picked by the ID.

[image]

Picture is a screenshot how the Command should look like.

Comment: is this your channel ? Are you member of this channel ? Maybe you don't have privilages to access this channel or `id` is wrong - and this is why you get `None`.  See [client.get_channel returns None #2282](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/2282#issuecomment-513530155) or [Trying to make a Discord bot with discord.py, getting errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42568534/trying-to-make-a-discord-bot-with-discord-py-getting-errors)

Comment: I am the owner of the server - I am in a "Bot test channel" which is private but the bot has access for reading and writing. Although I want to post a message in other channels than the "bot test" channel. And instead of making a new command for every channel i want to freely pick a channel by it's ID. 
Since I'm the owner i have access to all created channels.

Comment: and did you check `print(id)` and `print(type(id))` to see what you use ?

Comment: Doesn't really have an effect after adding it to:
```@client.command()
async def msg(ctx, channel, *, content):
    print(id) and print(type(id))
    channel = client.get_channel(id)
    await channel.send(content)```

Comment: if you don't get any text in console/terminal when you run it then you have empty string in `id` - and maybe this makes your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because `channel` is `None`.
For example: if you print the channel type like so

```
@client.command()
async def send(ctx, channel, *, content):
    channel = client.get_channel(channel)
    print(type(channel))
    # await channel.send(content)
```

Your output would be `<class 'NoneType'>`. To fix this you can pass `int` to your channel output like so:

```
@client.command()
async def send(ctx, channel, *, content):
    channel = client.get_channel(int(channel))
    await channel.send(content)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked! I wasn't able to "remote control" channels. I wanted to make sure the only messages in a channel are bot messages - similar to a "suggestion" command